How can I change the background of VS Code native tabs on macOS?

I enabled the multiple tab in VS Code, and now I want to change the background color in the picture where the arrow point at.

VS Code doesn't have control over that. That's a specific feature of macOS (which VS Code includes support for, and allows opting into usage of (see On VS Code on macOS, how to keep two projects open in macOS window tabs (instead of two windows)?)), and it's under the control of macOS. I assume if you change your system theme between dark/light, it will also change between dark/light, but that would be the extent of its configurability... probably (I don't use macOS much).
